# Netbeans custom files in project

Tags: netbeans

I need to add some custom files into my Java project in Netbeald, so after each build it will copy them automatically into output folder.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may tweak your build.xml like this:

```
<target name="-post-jar">
        <copy file="my/dir/file.txt" todir="build/classes/my/package"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't store those files together with the Java files, then add the directory where they are located to the project as a "Source Package Folder"

Everything in the "Source Package Folders" will automatically be copied to the build directory.

Comment: can I commit them into git as well?

Comment: Sure, if that directory is under git control

Comment: git will take "everything", while not ignored, from the  folder under git control